# Test result reporting

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using TestNG and Selenium webdriver via Java.

Is there any tool that can help generate detailed test results, for example, suppose I have a test case that fails more often than not, is there a tool that can statistically report those test cases that fail more often than the others like in a graph, or pie chart, etc?

Answer (score 2):

**XL Testview**

Have a look at [XL Testview](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-testview/) from [XebiaLabs](https://xebialabs.com/).

> Test analytics and decision support that spans testing tools
>
> - See all your test results in one single dashboard
> - Analyze test results across multiple test tools
> - Track release metrics and quality trends over time
> - Use real-time quality data to make the best go/no-go release decisions

I havent used it, but seems to track results over time. Seems pretty interesting.

**Test Result Analyzer**

Or have a look a the [Test Result Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin) plugin for [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

> Many of us have a requirement of knowing the execution status of a
>   test package , test class or test-method across multiple builds. This
>   plugin is an implementation of the said requirement and shows a table
>   containing the executions status of a package,class or a test-method
>   across builds.

This plugin supports jUnit and TestNG results sets. Looks like the minimum you want and it is free. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Tesults](https://www.tesults.com) - it handles all this including identifying recurring / continuing fails. In general it's a great central place for a team to view and assign failing tests. Please be aware that I work at Tesults.